# Runlevel of choice. GRUB, ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, grub, runlevel

I'm quite new to linux, and have a few questions regarding my assignment.

1. I must give a choice to the user in GRUB, to use either 3rd or 4th runlevel. May i ask for any materials and/or tips on that?
2. I have to make a certain service start automatically only at the 4th runlevel. In notes from my lecturer he mentioned putting rc scripts in /etc/rc.d directory, but i don't have one, with such name. Instead i have files like: rc0.d, rc1.d ... rc6.d. Are those the directories i should be putting my scripts in, and are these numbers in their names, corresponding to the runlevels?

And also, i have an SSH, on my ubuntu on my VirtualBox. I want to be able to connect there through my host machine with windows, and i can do that easily, as long as PasswordAuthentication is on, cause when i turn it off and rely solely on public key, i get access denied. So the problem here is me not knowing how to apply the publickey to my host machine (ssh-copy-id doesn't work, tried also just echoing the publickey to authorized_keys in the proper localization, but it didn't work either)

Any links with the information that i need, is also appreciated.

Comment: please do research before posting here ... question #2 has been answered before

Comment: look at this example ... how would you edit menu.lst file to duplicate one of the grub menu entries ... how would you modify the menu entry to specify run level?

Comment: you don't have to make any changes to menu.lst file ... you can do experiments at boot time ... grub allows you to edit command lines ... it makes no change to the file itself ... if you make a mistake, then just reboot and try again

Comment: Have in mind, most recent Linux distros do not use SysV init and runlevels; they have switched to systemd. So in order to experiment propeply with runlevels, either install an old Ubuntu, or a SysV distro like Slackware, Devuan, Artix.